# Apacite with natbitapa - bibliography spacing

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I am using a LaTeX template for my thesis

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib]{memoir}
```

Apacite is working fine for the in-text citations but the bibliography has strange spacing - each author, journal and doi start on a new line.
If I use `\bibligraphstyle{apalike}` the references section is correclty formatted but the in-text citations that should use "&" are changed to "and".

At the moment this is what I'm using:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{biblio}
```

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Please consider editing your posting to create a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001).